# C++ Object Oriented Equivalent of bitMasks

Tags: c++, oop, bitmask

Keeping it short and simple, what is the modern day industry accepted way of doing bitmasks in C++? To be more specific, how do you handle multiple and variable number of options in your function declarations?

i.e. Imagine you have a function with optional and variadic options ala the flags passed to system calls.

Comment: There's always `std::bitset`. I haven't really found anything completely perfect for flags with a type and a separate enclosing scope, though.

Comment: There... is no C++ way of doing bitmasks... unless I am misunderstanding your question. Bitmasks are identical from C.

Comment: I think the industry-accepted way of using bitmasks is using bitmasks.

Answer (score 0):

No. Bitmasks work the same as they did in C.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of work, you can get some extra type-safety compared to an ordinary C-like bitmask.

```
#include <type_traits>

enum class MyOpts {
    OPT1 = 1<<0,
    OPT2 = 1<<1,
    OPT3 = 1<<2,
    OPT_ALL = OPT1 | OPT2 | OPT3
};

#define MYOPTS_BINARY_OP(OP) \
    inline MyOpts operator OP(MyOpts a, MyOpts b) { \
        using num_type = std::underlying_type<MyOpts>::type; \
        return static_cast<MyOpts>( static_cast<num_type>(a) OP \
                                    static_cast<num_type>(b) ); \
    } \
    inline MyOpts& operator OP ## = (MyOpts& a, MyOpts b) { \
        a = a OP b; \
        return a; \
    }

MYOPTS_BINARY_OP( | )
MYOPTS_BINARY_OP( & )
MYOPTS_BINARY_OP( ^ )
#undef MYOPTS_BINARY_OP

inline MyOpts operator~(MyOpts opts) {
    return static_cast<MyOpts>(
        ~static_cast<std::underlying_type<MyOpts>::type>(opts) & OPT_ALL );
}
```

I'll commonly do this sort of thing whenever I create a bitmask, but I can't say I've seen it as "industry accepted".